# Old Version of gef4?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef, zest

I'm working with a softwareproject, which needs the following packages:

```
import org.eclipse.gef4.zest.layouts.LayoutAlgorithm;
import org.eclipse.gef4.zest.layouts.dataStructures.DisplayIndependentRectangle;
import org.eclipse.gef4.zest.layouts.interfaces.EntityLayout;
import org.eclipse.gef4.zest.layouts.interfaces.LayoutContext;
```

But I can't find the right plugin to solve this issue.
I installed the following plugins from: https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/gef4-master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/update-site:

```
GEF4 Geometry
GEF4 Geometry Documentation
GEF4 Geometry SDK
GEF4 Geometry Devoloper Resources
GEF4 Zest Documentation
GEF4 Zest SDk
```

And Eclipse still doesn't know the package:

```
org.eclipse.gef4.zest.layouts
```

I think that an old version of Gef4 Zest is used in the software project and the new versions have an other structure or something like that.

Does anyone have the same problem and/or know how to solve it?

Comment: It can't really be very old because GEF 4 is the current development version of GEF. Because it is still in development it is possible these APIs have changed (I don't know enough about GEF 4 to say for sure).

Comment: Which packages *are* in the Zest SDK?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? I'm having a similar issue trying to import org.eclipse.gef4.zest.core.widgets.Graph;

Answer (score 3):

The org.eclipse.gef4.zest.layouts packages have been migrated into an own component, namely GEF4 Layout, which is provided on the update-sites.

The classes/interfaces you mentioned above have been migrated as follows:
- o.e.g4.zest.layouts.LayoutAlgorithm -> o.e.g4.layout.ILayoutAlgorithm
- o.e.g4.zest.layouts.interfaces.EntityLayout -> o.e.g4.layout.IEntityLayout
- o.e.g4.zest.layouts.interfaces.LayoutContext -> o.e.g4.layout.ILayoutContext

The DisplayIndependentRectangle is no longer provided, instead the Layout classes use the Rectangle (o.e.g4.geometry.planar.Rectangle) abstraction provided by the GEF4 Geometry component.

Answer (score 0):

You should also install the `GEF4 Layout` feature from the update site you linked to.

Comment: Ok, i installed the GEF4 Layout feature, but it still doesn't work. :(